# Function in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> I want to show that if we consider a polynomial $V$ in $R[X_1,...,X_n]$
>   such that $V$ is negative near infinity then $e^{-V(X)}\notin L^2(\mathbb R^n)$.

This is what I tried to do:

$V$ is negative  near infinity $\implies$ there exists $R>0$ such that $∀X,||X||≥R$ then $V(X)<0$ $\implies$ there exists $ R>0$ such that $∀X,||X||≥R$ then $e^{−2V(X)}>1$.

Or $$∫_{\mathbb R^n}|e^{−V(X)}|^2dx=∫_{\mathbb R^n}e^{−2V(X)}dx≥∫_{||X||≥R}e^{−2V(X)}dx≥∫_{||X||≥R}1dx=∞,$$
hence $e^{−V(X)}∉L^2(\mathbb R^n)$.

Please tell me if there is a mistake in my answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think tha my answer is correct.But i want to prove a better result given by: If a polynomial $V(x)$ in $R[x_1,x_2,..,x_n] $ satisfies $∀ M≥0$ there exist $x∈R^n$ such that $ ||x||≥M$ and $V(x)≤0$ then $e^{−V(x)}∉L^2(R^n)$.can someone help me please?

Comment: If that's the question you want answered, then you should put that question in the main post (or make a new post), not in a comment. (Your proof in the post looks essentially correct; what you're proving is that any function $f(X)$ such that $f(X) \ge 1$ when $|X|\ge R$ cannot possibly be in $L^2(\Bbb R^n)$, or indeed in any $L^p(\Bbb R_n)$.)

Comment: i asked the question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757720/minimum-of-a-polynomial    but there is no answer.

Comment: ... give it more than one minute....

Comment: I asked the question before a day here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757080/exponential-of-a-polynomial?noredirect=1#comment3585655_1757080 but the is no answer and then i tried to answer is my self here today math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757720/ and there is no answer also