# Minimum of a Polynomial

Tags: real-analysis

Let $V(X)$ be a polynomial in $R[X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n]$ satisfing the following property: 
forall $R \ge 0$, there  exist $X \in R^n$ such that $\|X\|\ge R$ and $V(X)\le 0$.

Does this imply that V admets a local minimum.

This is what I tried to do:

We have

$$\forall R\ge 0~\exists    ~~ X \in R^n ~~ R\le \|X\|, ~~V(x)\le 0$$

or

$$\int _{R^n} \left|e^{-V(X)}\right|^2 dx=\int _{R^n} e^{-2V(X) }dx =\lim_{R \rightarrow 0}  \int _{R\le \|X\|} e^{-2V(X)}dx \ge \lim_{R \rightarrow 0} \int _{R\le \|X\|} e^{-\inf \left\{V(X)\colon V(X)\le 0\right\}} dx\ge \lim_{R \rightarrow 0}  \int_{R\le \|X\|} 1 dx=+\infty$$

because $e^{-\inf\left\{V(X) \colon V(X)\le 0\right\}} \ge 1$

Finaly we get
$e^{-V(X)} \notin L^2(R^n)$

Can someone please correct my answer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $L^2(R^n)$? I am also struggling to derive the first integral equality.

Comment: $u\in L^2(R^n) if ∫_{R^n}|u(x)|^2dx $ is finite (it is the space of square integable functions)